# csh one liner to compare 2 zipped text files

Tags: unix, csh

I'm trying to compare 2 .gz text files using zcat and diff.  This is on a JunOS box, so adding new binaries (zdiff) is not an option and only a limited number of other shells are available.  It may be true that these things could be added, but admin policy prohibits this.  csh is the default shell, but **tcsh**, and **sh** could be used also.  I want to be able to compare a pending commit file (juniper.conf+.gz) with the current config file (juniper.conf.gz), in the /config dir.

I've read that something like

```
diff <(zcat juniper.conf+.gz) <(zcat juniper.conf.gz)
```

would work, but apparently that's only avail on bash.

This,

```
zcat juniper.conf+.gz | { zcat juniper.conf.gz | diff /dev/fd/3 - ; } 3<&0
```

produced a "missing name for redirect" message (not that I fully understood the command to begin with).

Might there be some other command line wizzardry to do this in one shot in csh (or other avail shell)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the features in the suggested commands are specific to bash, or at least to sh.

If `sh` really is the Bourne shell, and not a symlink to `bash` or `ksh` as it is on many systems, you can't use things like `<(command)` or `3<&0` -- and csh just doesn't have features like that.

This should work with csh:

```
zcat juniper.conf+.gz > 0 ; zcat juniper.conf.gz > 1 ; diff 0 1 ; rm 0 1
```

Or you might try your second command:

```
zcat juniper.conf+.gz | { zcat juniper.conf.gz | diff /dev/fd/3 - ; } 3<&0
```

with sh; a csh one-liner that does this is:

```
sh -c 'zcat juniper.conf+.gz | { zcat juniper.conf.gz | diff /dev/fd/3 - ; } 3<&0'
```

(I'm tempted to suggest a csh one-liner that starts with

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.2.tar.gz && ...
```

but you probably can't build bash from source on JunOS.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your first suggestion is really quite sufficient. I was trying to find something more complicated, but really just banging them out as seperate commands on a single line would be perfectly acceptable (it feels like one step). You just needed to readjust my head.  The second suggestion didn't work.  There is no /dev/fd/3 file (i'm certainly no shell scripter, obviously); I found an article that talked about /dev/fd but TLDR.  Lastly, the suggestion to install/build bash would be great, but sadly not on our production network. Thanks again!